# Multi-select input doesn't disable default value on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, safari

I have a search form on my site, with a select control that looks roughly like this:

```
<select name="foo" size="5"  multiple="multiple">
  <option value="" selected="selected">All</option>
  <option value="AAAS">African and African American Studies</option>
  <option value="ANTH">Anthropology and Archaeology</option>
  <option value="APMA">Applied Mathematics</option>
  ...
</select>
```

On a desktop browser, the behavior is that "All" is selected by default, but when a different value is clicked, all becomes unselected unless a modifier key is hit. Obviously there are no modifier keys on iOS, so the behavior there is different, and "All" stays selected even when I click on "Applied Math" or whatever.

So, the simplest answer would be to either just not have anything selected on any browser, or accept the iOS behavior. Neither is terribly palatable. What I'd like is for the default to get deselected when another choice is made, but from that point on allow multiselect to work as iOS expects it to. Should I just throw in a little javascript, or is there a pure-html solution?